# Flutter API fetch code throws "index out of range" using Bloc

Tags: arrays, flutter, list, gridview

i use bloc for state management to fetch data from api

```
  FutureOr<void> fetchAllDrinksList(
      GetAllDrinksList event, Emitter<HomeState> emit) async {
    await apiRepository.getAllDrinks().then((value) {
      emit(state.copyWith(
        status: HomeStatus.success,
        drinksList: value,
        message: 'success',
      ));
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      emit(state.copyWith(
          status: HomeStatus.failure, message: error.toString()));
    });
  }
```

and display to home page, like this

```
GridView.builder(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 40,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                        childAspectRatio: 0.7,
                      ),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      padding:
                          EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 25),
                      itemCount: state.tempDrinksList.isEmpty
                          ? state.drinksList.length
                          : state.tempDrinksList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final drink = state.drinksList[index];
                        final filterDrinks = state.tempDrinksList[index];
                        if (state.tempDrinksList.isNotEmpty) {
                          return buildGridContainer(
                              filterDrinks); //for filter drinks
                        } else {
                          return buildGridContainer(drink); //for non-filter
                        }
                      },
                    );
```

i have rest of code of ui card for display data from drinks List but i got an error for Flutter API fetch code throws "index out of range" i thinks problem is length of state.drinksList but i use print statement to debug item on list but i get data by use state.drinksList[index].name

Thanks!

[Here is my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0RPV.png)

Comment: Sorry for my english skill, error is have 14 items of card that equal to my response from api but it red color and have error is "RangeError (index) Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0" the number of error is +1 by each card example is :
 "RangeError (index) Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 1",
"RangeError (index) Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 2", .... , 14

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing elements from `state.drinksList` and `state.tempDrinksList` using the same index, which may result in accessing an index that doesn't exist in one of the lists. This can happen if the lengths of the two lists differ or if the indices are not synchronized properly.

```
GridView.builder(


physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    crossAxisSpacing: 40,
    mainAxisSpacing: 20,
    childAspectRatio: 0.7,
  ),
  shrinkWrap: true,
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30, horizontal: 25),
  itemCount: state.tempDrinksList.isEmpty
      ? state.drinksList.length
      : state.tempDrinksList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    if (state.tempDrinksList.isNotEmpty) {
      // Use index to access element from tempDrinksList
      final filterDrink = state.tempDrinksList[index];
      return buildGridContainer(filterDrink);
    } else {
      // Use index to access element from drinksList
      final drink = state.drinksList[index];
      return buildGridContainer(drink);
    }
  },
);
```

Comment: i do follow with your answer but my whole screen is white cannot do anything’s 
but why i change BlocBuilder to FutureBuilder it's working ?

Comment: Is your problem solved  now?

Comment: not yet pls help

Comment: I  edit my answer check this

Comment: it's same error

Comment: i have a choice chip to display filter of Drinks type (eg: coffee, tea) when i selected choice it's working fine , but when app is open data for initial it's error for show all data

Comment: you give all the code in `GridView.builder` and i can get an idea

Comment: i edit my questions  to give all of GridView.builder

Comment: i just new graduate from computer science and learning about flutter bloc , Do you have any useful source to learn?

Comment: I can't say for sure but i think you can use YouTube, and Medium good luck bro